# ngRepeat: Limit based on total character length instead of number of items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using an ng-repeat to list out a set of items in a span tag. The problem is that I run out of room in my div so I need to limit the items. I've tried limitTo:3, but I run into a problem there where some of the words are longer than others so it still runs over.

So is there a way I can count the total number of letters and use something like limitTo so I can keep it in the space I have available?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is join your items into one string and then cut it off using [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo).

Your HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Test"> 
        <span>{{arrayString | limitTo:maxLength}}</span>
 <span ng-show="arrayString.length > maxLength" ng-click="maxLength=arrayString.length" class="clickable">Show More</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your controller;

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Test', function ($scope) {
    $scope.maxLength = 10;
    $scope.array = ['one', 'long', 'string'];

    $scope.$watch('array', function (newValue) {
        $scope.arrayString = newValue.join(' ');
    });

});
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TwoToneBytes/pt6ytxL9/6/)

Comment: I'm trying to keep the entire output from all the items down to say 20 characters, not just limit individual items.

Comment: That's closer... Is there a way that I could keep track of which items were there and which ones weren't? Like have a 'show more' button at the end and be able to list the other ones?